# Making Thumbnail images using a file

Tags: c#, thumbnails

I'm wondering if there is any disadvantages of using a file to make a thumbnail for an existing image instead of saving it into disk . Is there any memory issues related with this ?! 
My code :

```
// thumbnails.aspx

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string file = Request.QueryString["i"];
    if (file == null)
        return;
    if (!IsFileExists(file))
        return;
    Thumb(file);
  }
public void Thumb(string file) 
{
    System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath(file));
    System.Drawing.Image thumbnailImage = image.GetThumbnailImage(70, 70, new System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback), IntPtr.Zero);
    System.IO.MemoryStream imageStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
    thumbnailImage.Save(imageStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    byte[] imageContent = new Byte[imageStream.Length];
    imageStream.Position = 0;
    imageStream.Read(imageContent, 0, (int)imageStream.Length);
    Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
    Response.BinaryWrite(imageContent);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you more clearly explain the  two options you are weighing? Instead of using System.Drawing and GDI you can use System.Windows.Media and WPF which is a lot more efficient.

Comment: I can save a thumbnail Image for example in a folder called "Thumbs" or I can Send the image file for a specific file which called Thumbnail.aspx which in turn return me a byte[] which contains a thumbnail for the image and this thumbnail not saved into disk

Comment: And what advantage gives me the using of WPF above GDI !!

Comment: @mrtsherman "Instead of using System.Drawing and GDI you can use System.Windows.Media and WPF which is a lot more efficient."   Do you have any supporting documentation/links for that claim?

Comment: @steve - http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2009/12/10/resizing-images-from-the-server-using-wpf-wic-instead-of-gdi.aspx - way down he has a benchmark. Fast WPF is about 3.5x faster than GDI.

Comment: @mrtsherman - Thanks for the link.  I'm baffled, you'd think the underlying graphics libraries would be the same for both environments.

Comment: @steve - I believe WPF has access to hardware accelerated rendering via the GPU. It also can use different algorithms which the article author touches on.

Comment: @mrtsherman - I wonder why the same techniques and algorithms aren't used by the .Net libraries for windows forms and asp.net?

Answer (score 0):

Store it on file then. Converting to thumbnail using GDI every time will use a lot of cpu cycles. You could also store the image in a database instead of on disk.

Comment: Be careful with storing on a database as this ends up using a lot of RAM on the DB server.